# istream::readsome doesn't read from console?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have written the above code to test "readsome" . When "read" is used the code works but needs to wait for an input of 0x10 characters to work.
With "readsome" nothing is read on my system ( ubuntu Linux 3.13.0-37 ).
Why ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    char s[0x11];int i=150;
    do{
        s[0]=0;
        std::cin.readsome(s,0x1);
        if(std::cin.gcount()>0)
            s[std::cin.gcount()]=0;
            if(std::cin.eof()) std::cout<<"EOF!"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<s;
        usleep(100000);
    }while(i--);
    std::cin.read(s,0x10);
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: what did you expect was the difference between `read` and `readsome`?

Comment: It would be usefull if readsome reads from the console the available data without waiting to collect all the data, while read waits for the indicated number of characters.

Comment: Yes, well, that is what happens. Define "all the data" - your computer program cannot see into the future!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome
"The behavior of this function is highly implementation-specific. For example, when used with std::ifstream, some library implementations fill the underlying filebuf with data as soon as the file is opened (and readsome() on such implementations reads data, potentially, but not necessarily, the entire file), while other implementations only read from file when an actual input operation is requested (and readsome() issued after file opening never extracts any characters). Likewise, a call to std::cin.readsome() may return all pending unprocessed console input, or may always return zero and extract no characters."

So readsome in the linux console case seems to be totally useless. ( if some body knows something different please inform ).

Answer (score 0):

`readsome` only extracts characters *already in the buffer*. It won't wait for any input.
From the standard ([istream.unformatted]/32):

> If `rdbuf()->in_avail() == -1`, calls `setstate(eofbit)` […], and
>   extracts no characters;
>   — If `rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0`, extracts no characters 
> — If
>   `rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0`, extracts `min(rdbuf()->in_avail(),n))`.

Comment: My problem is that I digit characters to got in the buffer, I hit return but nothing is "readsome".

Comment: Yes, but you call `readsome` and **then** you enter stuff into the console. As I mentioned in my answer readsome **doesn't wait** for input, therefore anything you write in the console is discarded.

Comment: No I call readsome and it reads nothing, after I call sleep(1) and it waits 1 second some times again and again until I write the characters and I hit return, at that time readsome should find the data entered but it doesn't.

Comment: You are aware that the characters you enter into the console are not even put into any buffer? I mean, at what point is there any extraction done?

Comment: The characters entered into the console, should go into cin.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis No. Just... no. There is nothing in the buffer so `in_avail` will return `0`; The rest is obvious.

Comment: I modified the code adding a counter and a final read, and the characters typed are normally buffered and existent. ( look at the modified code )